# Replace XML nodes with handlebars.js statements

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I'm trying to build a simple way for non programmers to define loops and conditional logic within an XML file.

I've decided to use `<Loop></Loop>` and `<Condition></Condition>` tags to handle these cases. The idea being that the Loop and Condition tags will be replaced with handlebars.js #each and #if statements within the XML e.g

```
<Meeting>
    <Loop Target="People">
        <Person> 
            <Name>{{Name}}</Name>
            <Surname>{{Surname}}</Surname>
        </Person>
    </Loop>
</Meeting>
```

Will need to end up as

```
<Meeting>
    {{#each People}}
        <Person> 
            <Name>{{Name}}</Name>
            <Surname>{{Surname}}</Surname>
        </Person>
    {{/each}}  
</Meeting>
```

And like wise for Condition tags being converted to the handlebars if statement.

I've attempted to use .Net's XDocument library but I'm struggling to figure out how to actually accomplish this (the `IXmlLineInfo` instance doesn't provide me with enough info).

It seems as if I may need a way to parse the raw string to get the start and end positions of both the opening tags and closing tags in order to do a straight up text replacement. But I'm not sure how to go about doing this in a manner that can handle the numerous edge cases that comes with editable text.

Comment: That's how I see your question - "I need to take child node of an XML node, remove it's original parent and add that child node back into grand-parent, than add two more text nodes before/after it as sibling. I don't like/understand/want/... XML APIs, how to do that with ... Regex?"... What exact problem you face when you try to do that with XML?

Comment: Also you may want to [edit] the question to show "non-XML" variant that you want to achieve (as currently question has none of such examples). Also clarify if C# is must or some basic XSLT would do.

Comment: Yeah that's a pretty good understanding, although I don't mind using an XML API, I just haven't figured out how to do it. I have attempted to take the child contents of the Loop and turn it into a string, surround the string with handle bars and then convert it to an XElement to add back into the document, but that threw an exception as it wasn't able to parse it. I consider the handlebars to be non-XML content, which is shown in the second example. C# only please, no XSLT.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+add+mixed+content+xml - unless you actually want to produce not-an-XML you are just looking for "mixed content" (so far nothing indicates that your desired output is not XML).  You want to add text+child+text into grand-parent node, you don't need to convert anything to strings.

Comment: Okay I think we're getting lost in semantics here so I've changed the title for the question to refer to handlebars directly.

Comment: But your comment did change the way I viewed this problem and has allowed me to figure out a way to solve it using XElement's `AddBeforeSelf` and `AddAfterSelf`methods to add raw text to the node in the correct place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this without needing to use raw string manipulation or the use of `IXmlLineInfo`.

When encountering a Loop element I simply:

```
//1. add the opening handlerbars code to the parent elemnet before the Loop element
loopNode.AddBeforeSelf("{{#each " + collection.Value + "}}");

//2. add all the loop element's children to the parent element just after the handlebars code
loopNode.AddBeforeSelf(loopNode.Elements());

//3. Add the closing handlebars statement to the parent after the Loop element
loopNode.AddAfterSelf("{{/each}}");

//4. Then finally remove the Loop element from the DOM
loopNode.Remove();
```

And I'm left with exactly what I need to send into the handlebars renderer.

Comment: Well done, btw in `XElement.Annotation()` there is the `LineInfoEndElementAnnotation` with the information for the End Element to every Element. It Requires reflection to get these.

Comment: How did you fix the formatting problem? Because by doing this you insert text nodes which would prevent child nodes from getting indented correctly.

Comment: When I was viewing it through XML visualizer in Visual Studio, it didn't seem to have any formatting issues after the replacement was done. But, having said that, this operation is transient and the end user for our app will never see the final XML with the handlebars code, they'll see the Loop and Condition tags when data capturing or the non XML data rendered in a report. So formatting wasn't a concern for me.